# How to parse XML data with some non-xml formatted elements at Python

Tags: xml-parsing, lxml, cisco

I have following answer from CUCM api:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns:executeSQLQueryResponse xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/12.5"><return><row><pkid>63d1f8a1-0964-caa0-d496-ff91340c236c</pkid><userid>Semenova.LA</userid><firstname/><lastname>Семенова</lastname><snrenabled>t</snrenabled><devicecount>1</devicecount><licensetype>Enhanced         </licensetype><licenses>1</licenses></row></return></ns:executeSQLQueryResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried to parse this answer. I used lxml library.

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring(response)
```

But I received following error

> File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3237, in lxml.etree.fromstring
> File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1891, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
> ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.

It looks as some element at answer in unsupported
If i cut response to

```
response='''<return><row><pkid>63d1f8a1-0964-caa0-d496-ff91340c236c</pkid><userid>Semenova.LA</userid><firstname/><lastname>Семенова</lastname><snrenabled>t</snrenabled><devicecount>1</devicecount><licensetype>Enhanced         </licensetype><licenses>1</licenses></row></return>'''
```

All works as expected
What should I do to fix it?
Should I delete unwanted element such as:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns:executeSQLQueryResponse xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/12.5">
```

How i can do this?

Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
root = etree.fromstring(response)
```

to

```
root = etree.fromstring(resp.encode())
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not resolve issue 'code' <Element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope at 0x1dcfa363740>

Answer (score 0):

I applied non-scalable solution - just cut begin and end string by template

```
cut_string ='''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns:executeSQLQueryResponse xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/12.5">'''
cut_string2 = '''</ns:executeSQLQueryResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>'''
s = response.replace(cut_string, "")
ss = s.replace(cut_string2, "")
root = etree.fromstring(ss.encode())
```

Are any more clever solution?

For example - get string between <`return>String</return>`